# Get document reference by using username

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get document reference from Firestore by using following code:

```
var sfDocRef = database.collection("tags").doc("567BHJV6JF95HVCF44HB");
```

Now if I hover over the `sfDocRef` it gives me

`(local var) sfDocRef: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>`

But my requirement is to get the address of the document w.r.t it's name. Not w.r.t its ID. For that purpose I'm using the following code:

```
var sfDocRef = database.collection("tags").where("userName", "==", userName);
```

Now this code is giving me following datatype if I hover over it:

```
(local var) sfDocRef: FirebaseFirestore.Query<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>
```

I want `DocumentReference` datatype, but not by using ID but by using username. Can I do that in a single line? I'm not finding any way in documentation to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query can have multiple results. So it doesn't return a singular `DocumentReference`, but instead returns a `Query` that can refer to multiple documents.

To get the actual document reference(s) you'll have to execute the query and loop over the results:

```
var query = database.collection("tags").where("userName", "==", userName);
query.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            // Document reference is available as doc.ref
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```